# How to Get DDL for Oracle Database for user having only restricted access

Tags: oracle, ddl

Can anyone help me in resolving ORA-01489 issue causing string concatenation too long.
I am trying to create DDL script from Oracle database with respect to Impala and used listAGG for getting datacolumn and it's dataType, this is were i am facing the issue of concatenation.
since i'm new to Oracle, i am stuck in resolving the issue caused due to ListAGG and large number of concatenation operation in the query, any optimized query is welcomed. Oracle version : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition.
Below is the query that i am using :

`

```
WITH META AS (
SELECT
        t.table_name 
      , t.column_name  AS columnName       
      , t.data_type AS DataType
      , t.DATA_LENGTH AS DataLENGTH
      , CASE WHEN t.DATA_Precision < 10 AND t.DATA_SCALE = 0 THEN 'INT'
        WHEN t.DATA_Precision < 19 AND t.DATA_SCALE = 0 THEN 'BIGINT'
        WHEN t.DATA_Precision > 19 AND t.DATA_SCALE > 0 THEN 'DECIMAL( ' || t.DATA_SCALE || t.DATA_Precision || ')'
        ELSE NULL END  AS DataPrecision 
      , uc.constraint_type AS ConstraintSymbol
      , t.NULLABLE AS Constraint_Text  
      , t.column_ID as COL_ID
FROM all_tab_columns t
LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns cc
ON (cc.table_name = t.table_name AND
    cc.column_name = t.column_name)
LEFT JOIN all_constraints uc
ON (t.table_name = uc.table_name AND
   uc.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name )
WHERE t.table_name = '$table' and t.owner='$schema'
ORDER BY t.column_ID
)
SELECT 
 'USE $$"DATABASE"' || chr(10)
  ||'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '  
  || table_name || chr(10)
  || '(' || chr(10)
  || TO_CLOB(ListAGG(columnName || ' ' || 
  TO_CLOB(ListAGG(columnName || ' ' || 
  -- IMPALA CONVERSIONS
  CASE WHEN DataType IN ('CHAR', 'NCHAR') THEN 'CHAR'
  WHEN DataType IN ('VARCHAR', 'NVARCHAR', 'VARCHAR2', 'NVARCHAR2') THEN 'VARCHAR'
  WHEN DataType IN ('DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DATETIME2', 'TIME') THEN 'TIMESTAMP'
  WHEN DataType = 'BINARY_DOUBLE' THEN 'DOUBLE'
  WHEN DataType = 'BINARY_FLOAT' THEN 'FLOAT'
  WHEN DataType IN ('BIT', 'BINARY', 'BLOB', 'CLOB', 'ROWID', 'UROWID', 'NCLOB', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER', 'INTERVALYM', 'INTERVALDS', 'LONG') THEN 'STRING'
  WHEN DataType = 'NUMBER' THEN DataPrecision
  ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END
  || CASE WHEN DataType NOT LIKE '%NUMBER%' THEN  '(' || TO_CHAR(DataLENGTH) || ')' END
  || CASE WHEN Constraint_Text like '%N%' THEN ' COMMENT "<source value>:not-nullable"' 
  WHEN Constraint_Text like '%Y%' THEN  ' COMMENT "<source value>:not-nullable"' END || ' '
  || CASE 
  WHEN ConstraintSymbol like '%P%' THEN ' COMMENT "<source value>:not-nullable|PK"' 
  WHEN ConstraintSymbol like '%U%' THEN ' COMMENT "<source value>:not-nullable|UNIQUE"' END || chr(10), ',' ) 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COL_ID)) 
 FROM META
GROUP BY table_name
```

`

Comment: Why not use the Oracle maintained capability [`dbms_metadata.get_ddl()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026)? It does all this and more, and returns a CLOB so there's no problem with ORA-01489

Comment: I don't have access to it, that's the reason behind this query.